# Querying firestore using multiple in clauses

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a product listing page (similar to any e-commerce site) where users are expected to filter products based on multiple attributes and multiple values per attribute.

Lets assume data model is as shown below,

**Product** 
    Category - Shirt 
    Size - Medium 
    Colour - Blue

**Dropdown filters on the search page would be**,
 1. Category: Shirts, T-Shirts, Trousers etc 
 2. Size: Medium, Large etc

I'm clueless as how to query firestore when user would like to search all Shirts & T-Shirts of Small & Medium sizes?

Query like this isn't supported in firestore,

```
Firebase.firestore().collection("Products")
    .where("Category", "in", ["Shirt, "T-Shirts"])
    .where("Size", "in", ["Medium", "Large"])
```

On top of this, I need to paginate the response so filtering on the client side doesn't seem like an option.

Please suggest if there is any option.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can only have a single `in` condition in the query, your current approach won't work. The only workaround I know of is to keep a separate field where each value is the combination of sizes that is available. So something like:

```
"available_in": "Medium_Large"
```

And then query with:

```
Firebase.firestore().collection("Products")
    .where("Category", "in", ["Shirt, "T-Shirts"])
    .where("available_in", "==", "Medium_Large")
```

This type of solution only works if the number of combinations is reasonable, but that seems to be the case here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Frank. I used few filters and values just to explain the scenario but my real app has multiple attributes on which filtering needs to be done and each attribute can have 100's of possible values. This looks like a serious limitation of firestore, wondering how ecommerce like search pages are built/ modelled using firestore.