# Ecommerce search like query using Firebase Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Below is the **Category** collection DB structure:

[image: Here is my CATERGORY collection DB structure]

and here is the **PRODUCT** collection DB structure:

[image: Here is the PRODUCT collection DB structure]

I want to create a search query like similar to AMAZOM were you can just type in "shoes" and get a list of saying men shoes, women shoes, sports shoes etc. or just type in the name of the product and fetch the product.

As per my knowledge of Firestore, I have written a search query were it fetches all the data similar to the inputed letter. For example let's say I type in "S it retrieves the list of product starting with "S", below image is the result of it:

[image: search result img]

But that is not what I wanted and I have little knowledge of how to construct that kind search query that I want. How can I get my result using Firestore? I can twitch the current DB structure if I can achieve what I want but I don't want to destroy the whole structure too.

Comment: I think that this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-filter-firestore-data-cheaper-705f5efec444) might help you achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you ,I think that is what im looking for so let me try it .

Comment: What is AMAZOM?

Comment: @JustGotStared is this issue resolved?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I think you made that mistake not me , since you edited my post .

Comment: @DivyaniYadav I look at the article shared by Alex Momo but it might lead to a problem . So I can say this is not resolved to the way I wanted

Comment: @JustGotStared You can look at the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71978357/revisions) to see whether I changed this or whether it has been there [from the beginning](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/71978357/1).

Comment: can you refer to this thread [1][https://stackoverflow.com/q/59534199/15774176] and [2][https://stackoverflow.com/q/60624654/15774176] is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve  this by using orderby(), startAt()  & endAt() query on Product name.

```
   ref.collection("Product/").orderBy("Product").startAt(text).endAt(text + 
   '\uf8ff').get();
```

this will return QuerySnapshot of products where name contains that text.